# how to generate microsoft word 2010 with phpWord

Tags: php

I am working on php project that I need to generate a microsoft 2010 document on fly and send the 64encoded document to a web server using cURL request. The web server only accept 2010 word. The 2007 word file I generated with the following code(using word2007 writer)was not accepted:

```
    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
    $section = $PHPWord->createSection();
    $section->addText(....);
    $section->addText(...);
    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord,'Word2007');
    $fileName = "example.doc";
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
```

---

Does anyone know how to generate a ms word 2010 file with php code?

Thanks!

Comment: MSWord 2010 uses OfficeOpenXML (docx) format, the same as MSWord 2007, MSWord 2013, etc.... there is no separate Word 2010 format... a file generated using PHPWord's Word2007 writer is OfficeOpenXML format.... but it's a `docx` file, not a `doc` file.... your MS 2010 is probably complaining that the extension doesn't match the format, give it the correct `.docx` extension

Comment: From [api doc](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#remove-compatibility-mode-text-in-the-ms-word-title-bar) there is a `setOoxmlVersion` method. Did you try? `$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(14);`

Comment: I added this line in the code, but the program stopped at $PhpWord->getCompatibility(). Here is my code:

Comment: @Chris:@chris:Here is my code, it stopped at the second line, how can I tell what is wrong? I am using Linux terminal and it is hard to debug:                                                                                                                    $PhpWord = new PHPWord();                                                                                                                           $compat = $PHPWord->getCompatibility();

Comment: @Mark, I tried to save the document as "doc" or "docx", neither worked.

Comment: @Chris, to make it clear, this stopped the program: $comp = $PhpWord->getCompatibility();

Comment: Except a typo or code that is out of date, I really don't know. Be aware I never used that library so it was just a suggestion. Even if the code works, I'm unsure about what it does. Aside note: you should edit your question with new attemtps. Avoid posting code in comments, that could be confusing.

Comment: Perhaps see if MS Word itself will read the file that you're generating.... at the very least, it might provide a more useful error message.